# Inverse function theorem and local diffeomorphisms

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, diffeomorphism, inverse-function-theorem

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3,   f(x,y,z) = (x,xy,z^2)$. Determine where $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Our lecturer gave us this definition

> Let $U \subset R^n$ be an open set and $x_0 \in U$. If $$f \in C^1(U, \mathbb{R}^n) \text{ such that } J_f(x_0) \ne 0$$ then $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at $x_0$.

So for the problem, I can just find the Jacobian determinant and restrict it so that the Jacobian matrix is invertible.

I have that $$Df(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ y && x && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 2z \end{bmatrix}$$

and $$\det(Df(x,y,z)) = 2xz.$$

Thus $f$ is locally invertible for all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which $xz \ne 0.$

However, they did not provide any proof for this and I'm left wondering why is this the case? This seems to be related to the inverse function theorem?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the inverse function theorem. The points where the differential is a linear isomorphism (where your matrix is invertible, e.g., where the determinant does not vanish) are points around which your map defines a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a linear isomorphism is just a bijective linear map. Is there a way I could see that the derivative is indeed a bijective linear map without looking at the determinant?

Comment: You have to show that the columns (or rows) of your matrix are linearly independent. You can use the way you prefer, but usually, when the matrix is a square matrix like in your case (it is always a square matrix if you want to use IFT) the determinant is the fastest way. An equivalent way is to look for the points where the kernel of your linear map reduces to the null vector.